# Different stages of life

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

What words do you usually use to refer to the different periods of your age? For instance, which words would work properly in the made-up example below?

**Note:** I have listed some words in age order, but please let me know if they sound odd or there are some better words or possibly fixed terms there.

Those were the days. I'll never forget...

> **1-** I passed all my **infancy/childhood** years in that house. 
>    **2-** I passed all my **teen/adolescence** years in that house. 
>    **3-** I passed all my **youth** years in that house. 
>    **4-** I passed all my **adulthood** years in that house.

Please let me know about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases here, the word is a noun and so you do not need "years"

> I passed my...
>   infancy
>   childhood
>   youth
>   adulthood
>   middle age
>   old age
>   dotage
>   ... in that house

(these roughly align to Shakespeares seven ages of man: infant, schoolchild, lover soldier, justice, old man, geriatric)

Or you could use some adjectives like "school years", "teenaged years" or "working years" or the imprecise "the best years of my life".

Comment: Thank you very much @James K for the informative and interesting reply.